# operators for enum inside class

Tags: c++, enums

I have a class which has `enum` members. These members require output operator. I know how to implement operator if `enum` is outside the class:

```
enum Type
{
    SMALL=1,
    MIDDLE=2,
    LARGE=3
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Type value){
    static std::map<Type, std::string> strings;
    if (strings.size() == 0){
        #define INSERT_ELEMENT(p) strings[p] = #p
        INSERT_ELEMENT(SMALL);     
        INSERT_ELEMENT(MIDDLE);     
        INSERT_ELEMENT(LARGE);             
        #undef INSERT_ELEMENT
    } 
    return out << strings[value];
}

class House
{
public:
    Type houseType;
    ...
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    House myhouse;
    std::cout << "This house is " << myhouse << std::endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

Is it possible to do it with `enum` inside the class? I tried in similar way, but it obviously fails because operator inside class does not allow second argument.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to do it with enum inside the class?

Yes, and it works in exactly the same way. You simply need to use the scope resolution operator since in that case the enum is no longer in global scope:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const House::Type value)
```

Comment: Thank You! Now it compiles, but does not work as I expect. I edited the output operator in the post, so that you can see the problem. When enum was outside the class, output of the code was, say, "This house is LARGE". Now when I have put enum inside the class, output is "This house is 3". Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your behaviour. Perhaps it's related to the fact that you're passing a `House` to `cout` rather than a `Type`?

Comment: Indeed there is a mistake produced during copying. In my code there is std::cout << "This house is " << myhouse.houseType << std::endl; But it is not related to output format problem.

Comment: Take a look at my test code which works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6477abfe3867d43c perhaps your code differs somehow?

Comment: Now it works. When I put enum in class, I copied operator below main() function. Now it works but I still wonder why it has such different behaviour it I just switch order. Can you explain?

Comment: @vargss if you didn't declare the stream operator overload before `main`, then you couldn't use it in `main`. Since non-scoped enumertaions are convertible to int, you were using `ostream& operator<<(int)` instead. If you had used a scoped enumeration, then it wouldn't have been convertible to `int` and the compiler would have failed with a message that no overload applies instead of silently using the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

You can again define `operator<<`, but basically make it a passthrough from `House` to `Type`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const House& value)
{
    out << value.houseType;
    return out;
}
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/6u5p4)